# List of Upcoming Launches from Area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Can we keep a list of area51 beta sites that have been confirmed for launch, awaiting design work or anything else.

I, for one, would like to see the designs before they're finalized, and possibly give my input. I am sure someone else could find another use for such a list

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple -- every time a site is ready to launch Jin will **post a design question with screenshots on that site's meta**. When you see that happen, you know the site is about to launch.

e.g.:

[Design for Physics-SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/design-for-physics-se)
[Design Ideas for Mathematics Site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site)
[Design for the official WordPress.SE site](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-the-official-wordpress-se-site)

etc, etc.

Therefore, go to the [Stack Exchange tag sets](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/) and follow the [discussion]+[design] tag across all meta sites.

(hmm, this means, we should make it easier to say "on all *meta* sites..")

Comment: or maybe "on all beta meta-sites"